# Set rails associations with a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have made a database with Rails for a card game. I have all the tables set up, one that has the card set list, and separate tables that have attacks, abilities, monsters, and items. I would have to add associations for every new card set that comes out. I'm trying to write a rake file that will automatically add the associations, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using seeds. rake db:seed is standard. Make sure your seeds.rb uses logic that won't remove existing data. You can use something like [dibber](https://github.com/reggieb/dibber) to help simplify the configuration of your seed data.

Comment: I have already made the part of the script to create the tables and input the data, now I need to link the tables.

Comment: You'll need to show us your table structure. Can you post some examples of your tables? I assume you understand how to set up association in rails, and are trying to do something unusual. That is, you've read and understand this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I know all about the associations with rails. Its not a simple database setup so I might just have to go with straight sql.Its creating alot of join tables and one to many relationships.

Comment: but if I do that will it effect the way I have to query when I write my app?